# NullPointerException when trying to get the password of a user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I keep getting a NullPointerException when I try to validate a login.

```
public boolean checkPassword(String name, String password) {

    FindIterable<Document> user = null; 

    user = collection1.find(new Document("_id", name));
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User not in database");
    }

    String passwordDB = user.first().get("password").toString();
    String passwordSplitted = passwordDB.split(",")[1];

    if (password.equals(passwordSplitted)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Whats the problem here? Any solutions?

Comment: You must put bit of your exception stacktrace. It helps debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Though as pointed by @Amit, it needs the exception stacktrace to identify the exact cause of it. Yet, few things to improve in your code are :-

1. Your `if` check for `user` doesn't stop your code from throwing an NPE

   ```
   if (user == null) {
       System.out.println("User not in database");
   }
   String passwordDB = user.first().get("password").toString(); // this is still reached.
   ```

   You might want to return or put the rest of the block in an else for the case when no document is found.

   ```
   if (user == null) {
       System.out.println("User not in database");
       return false; // inferring your shared piece of code for default returns false
   }
   ```
2. Make sure the string split by you has the character `,` in it for sure. Since you are accessing the second substring after delimiting in your line of code -

   ```
   String passwordSplitted = passwordDB.split(",")[1]
   ```